# Need to remove specific parameter from url

Tags: regex, lua, gsub

I am new to the Lua library, I have one use case which I have to remove on a specific parameter and its value:
for example:

`String 1 : ?xyz=true&toekn=4234dadsasda`

`String 2 : ?toekn=4234dadsasda&test=pass`

Need output like this after removing token and its value

`String 1 : ?xyz=true`

`String 2 : ?test=pass`

I have tried the below Lua gsub function but no luck:

`string.gsub(args, "token=.*", " ")`

any help apricated, thanks

Comment: Why did you try `token=.*`? There is no `token` in your strings.

Comment: There is a typo on string 1 and string 2 it token not toekn

Comment: Try `text:gsub("&?token=[^&]+&?", "")` if you can only have 2 params and no more than 2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to considers additional conditions (using `&` and `;` as separators[1]) and corner cases (trailing separators and substrings with `token`):

```
text:gsub("([&;]?)%f[%a]token=[^&;]+([&;]?)",
  function(s1, s2) return s1 and s2 and #(s1..s2) > 1 and s1 or "" end)
```

This solution works correctly on query strings that include parameters like `subtoken` and that use `;` as separators. The template is using `%f[%a]`, which is a [frontier pattern](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) that describes a zero-length boundary where non-letter changes to a letter (this includes the first character in a string).

[1] W3C recommends that all web servers support semicolon separators in addition to ampersand separators to allow application/x-www-form-urlencoded query strings in URLs within HTML documents without having to entity escape ampersands ([wikipedia article on query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms)).

Answer (score 1):

If you can only have two query params and no more than two as shown in your input you can use

```lua
text:gsub("&?token=[^&]+&?", "")
```

Or, if you have multiple query params, you can use

```lua
text:gsub("([&?])token=[^&]+&?", "%1"):gsub("(.*)&$", "%1")
```

See the [online Lua demo #1](https://ideone.com/sb82XN) and the [online Lua demo #2](https://ideone.com/IyiRwa).

*Details*:

- `&?` - an optional `&`
- `token=` - a literal string
- `[^&]+` - one or more chars other than `&`
- `&?` - an optional `&` char.

In the second solution, `:gsub("([&?])token=[^&]+&?", "%1")` replaces the match with either `?` or `&` before the `token`, and the next `gsub("(.*)&$", "%1")` removes the `&` at the end of string in case the param occurs at the end of string.

Comment: Pankaj did not specify, and not sure if applicable, but what if there are more parameters and the token is in the middle? `"?xyz=true&token=4234dadsasda&foo=bar"` should likely return `"?xyz=true&foo=bar"`

Comment: @PeterThoeny I added another solution for that scenario.